# How can I pass my user entered information to my database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

The users enter their name and number in the textfields. The this information is passed then sent to the data.php file where I am trying to get it to write to my database. The data base name is called hello.

```
<!-- connect to database -->
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "hello";

// Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "wooo connected";
}

//<!-- post added information to database -->
if ($_POST['name']) {
 if ($_POST['number']) {

 $sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number)
VALUES ('', '$_POST['name']', '$_POST['number'')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
  }
 } 
} ?>
```

From looking at my code I believe the issue is with this line.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number)
VALUES ('', '$_POST['name']', '$_POST['number']')";
```

There is a blank left at the star for the auto incremented id that I have set in phpmyadmin.
I can hard code an entry such as:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number)
VALUES ('', 'john', '12345)";
```

These hard coded entries are put into the database but i can't get the user entered data to go in.

Comment: When you examine the console information, do you see the return value from the php file? Does it return "ERROR: Could not..."?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: thanks just learning how to do all this literally only started yesterday, I will learn how to do prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're about to go down a slippery slope using mysqli. I'd recommend trying to learn to use [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) for making queries. Right now, someone could easily put SQL into the `name` POST data and actually do damage to your database.

Anyways, your problem at hand, you have a missing bracket and one issue:

`VALUES ('', '$_POST['name']', '$_POST['number'')";`

It won't work as intended with nested single quotes.

`VALUES ('', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[number]')";`

Comment: MySQLi is no more slippery than anything else when done correctly. PDO can be just as bad if you do not use prepared statements.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yup, the guide I linked covers everything pretty thoroughly. It's very good at explaining why to do things instead of simply saying "do this," I just figured it's best to learn PDO and prepared statements in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Create variables for the `$_POST` values and add the vars for ease of code understanding:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number) VALUES ('', $name, $number)";
```

---

One reason your code may not be working because you have the single quotes around the `$_POST` values, then you can also do what Jasbeer Rawal recommended.

### UPDATE

Based on the kind comments... I would personally take a different approach to adding the data to your database, instead use prepared statements. I use MySQLi, but you can also use PDO.

Start by creating your connection:

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "");
define("PASSWORD", "");
define("DATABASE", "");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "There was a slight problem, please contact your webmaster before continuing.";
    exit();
}
```

Then when the user submits the form handle it:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT hello (name, number) VALUES (?, ?)"))
    {
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $number);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
}
```

This will add `$name` and `$number` and your `ID` role has to be a primary role and set to `auto_increment`. IDs will be automatically generated.

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: LOL *"slight problem"* ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ^ slight problem?

Comment: Yup, I try to make the errors a bit more "friendly" if I can

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from $_POST['name'] and $_POST['number'] as below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number) 
VALUES ('', $_POST['name'], $_POST['number'])";
```

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

Your insert code be like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hello (id, name, number) 
VALUES ('','{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['number']}')";
```

Then your value will be in database
If field `id` is primary key and auto increment then  your insert statement should be like

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hello ( name, number) 
VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['number']}')";
```

Comment: Turn the tide against teaching/propagating sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: Okay mistake from my part